# Emojis not getting swapped when text is toggled

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to toggle between texts using javascript but when I try to add emojis, they aren't getting swapped. I'm unable to use classic emoji symbols due to some limits so I'm using Dec values given in html emojis reference ex:`&#656557;`. Here's the code. Can anyone please provide me a code which can swap emojis too? https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/zYqQbmM

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("darkbutton1");
  if (x.innerHTML === "&#127771; Lights Off!!") {
    x.innerHTML = "&#127774; Lights On!!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "&#127771; Lights Off!!";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="darkbutton1" onclick="myFunction1()">&#127771; Lights Off!!</button>
```

Comment: Please include code here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) for HTML/CSS/JS snippets.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, i have added  snippet, Can you please help me regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably guessed (judging by your second example in the codepen), the issue with `darkbutton1` is that `innerHTML` doesn't equal `"&#127771; Lights Off!!"`. Instead, it equals `" Lights Off!!"`.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("darkbutton1");
  if (x.innerHTML === " Lights Off!!") {
    x.innerHTML = "&#127774; Lights On!!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "&#127771; Lights Off!!";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="darkbutton1" onclick="myFunction1()">&#127771; Lights Off!!</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou, This is what i'm expecting form

Comment: @ManiacPiano You're welcome. Consider clicking the check mark next to this answer to indicate that you accept it~

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd do this in one `<script>` tag placed at the bottom of the HTML structure, like this:

```js
const x = document.querySelector("#darkbutton1");
let isButtonActive = false;

x.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (isButtonActive) {
    isButtonActive = false;
    x.innerHTML = "&#127771; Lights Off!!";
  } else {
    isButtonActive = true;
    x.innerHTML = "&#127774; Lights On!!";
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="darkbutton1">&#127771; Lights Off!!</button>
```

`isButtonActive` is here just to keep track of the button's state (light or dark mode).
I think that adding the listeners in the script is better than calling it inline in HTML.